# moment.calendar() without the time

Tags: javascript, python, momentjs

I would like to use the moment.calendar() option without the time... so instead of 
"Last Tuesday at 5pm" I want "Last Tuesday". 
Does anybody know whether moment has a solution for that by now?
I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nawxZ/, which apparently shows a solution for that, but I can't see how this is supposed to work?
thanks
carl

```
function log(str) {
    $('body').append('<p>' + str + '</p>');
}

log(moment().calendar());
log(moment().calendar(true));
```

Answer (score 54):

starting from moment 2.10.5  you can do:

```
moment(/*your date*/).calendar(null,{
    lastDay : '[Yesterday]',
    sameDay : '[Today]',
    nextDay : '[Tomorrow]',
    lastWeek : '[last] dddd',
    nextWeek : 'dddd',
    sameElse : 'L'
})
```

see: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

Comment: how can get this localised? Getting "Today" for locale "en", and "Heute" for locale "de"? Thanks

Comment: moment already has all translations just change the locale using moment.lang(“de”) check the documentation

Comment: I did, but the results are not translated, only 'dddd' part is being translated. It takes [Today] as static text not dynamic localised. Check this: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4439

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't do what the question asks -- time is still output ("Tomorrow at 12:00 AM")

Comment: Thanks for challenging that, @FareedAlnamrouti! I had used a random jsfiddle to test that parameter but didn't notice until now that the momentjs version being used was too old (2.2). I tested again with the latest version and it does indeed work: https://jsfiddle.net/fLn5986j/

Comment: You can do something like this to get localized versions: 

`sameDay: ${currentLocaleData.calendar('sameDay', moment(value))},`

Comment: To get the above localized, use `locale` and **do not mention the calendar object** (it overrides the values for all language otherwise) .ie. just write as follows `moment(/*your date*/).locale(/*your locale*/).calendar()`.

Answer (score 7):

`moment().calendar()` supports custom formatted strings and formatting functions.

```
moment().calendar();
>> "Today at 9:06 AM"
```

Then set your formatted strings

```
moment.locale('yourlang', {
    calendar: {
        lastDay: function () {
            return '[last]';
        },
        sameDay: function () {
            return '[Today]';
        }
    }
});

moment().calendar();

// Will now output
>> "Today"
```

should do the trick. The [docs are an invaluable source](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/)

Comment: with your solution I need to define calendar for all supported languages of an app.. :/

Comment: 3 years ago that would be the case - I am not sure how it works today!

Comment: today seems to be the same case :/

Answer (score 5):

this is working perfectly. try it.

(moment(time).calendar().split(" at"))[0]

Comment: Thanks!

Note that if you're planning to switch to any other locales you should use
    (moment().calendar().split(" "))[0]
instead

eg. "Aujourd’hui à 16:30" (fr) or "heute um 16:30 Uhr" (de) would not work otherwise

Comment: not working for other locales, @CREOFF even your fix is not working for some locales.. because in some locales the future day of this week has two words. For example in locale 'sk' it is 'Vo štvrtok o 15:30' meaning 'On Thursday at 15:30'.

Comment: @Luckylooke Yes, you should check the logic for all locales you want to support. The more languages, the more intelligent your script should be. Belgian sites are usually limited to NL, FR, DE, EN so easier to test

Answer (score 2):

Since Moment `2.25.0` it is now possible to call *moment.calendar(formats)* without reference time value

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

Answer (score 1):

This code works partially. The problem lies on separating the word **at** from **[Today at]**.

In the example below, **a las** (means **at** in English) is part of the result.

```
moment().locale()
// "es"

moment().calendar(null, {
    sameDay: function (now) {
        var sameDay = now._locale._calendar.sameDay

        if (typeof sameDay === 'function') {
            sameDay = sameDay.call(this)
        }

        return sameDay.replace(' LT', '')
    }
})
// "hoy a las"
```

If the translations were "[Today] [at] LL", we would be able to separate the word **at**.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirement and unfortunately this is not supported currently (version 2.24.0).

If you look at an arbitrary language file, like [en-gb.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/en-gb.js), you can see that all the calendar variants contain the time.
There is no option to leave out the time. That would require a variant of calendar without the time for every language.

Answer (score 0):

I created an angular directive that provides a calendar with the date only.
If you don't use angular, just use the function.

```
 app.filter('amCalendarDate', function($translate) {
    return function(dt) {
        var md = moment(dt), key = '';

        if (!dt || !md || (md + '').toLowerCase() == 'invalid date')
            return '';

        var today = moment();
        var diff = today.diff(md, 'days');

        if (!diff)
            key = 'Today';
        else if (diff == -1)
            key = 'Tomorrow';
        else if (diff == 1)
            key = 'Yesterday';
        else if (Math.abs(diff) <= 6) {
            if (diff < 0)
                key = 'Next';
            else
                key = 'Last';

            var days = 'Sunday_Monday_Tuesday_Wednesday_Thursday_Friday_Saturday'.split('_');

            today.day(diff);

            key += ' ' + days[today.day()];
        }

        if (key) {
            // if you don't have translate, just return the key
            return $translate.amCalendarDate[key];
        } else
            return md.format('L');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have custom times set and are only working on a day base, you can use this simple and multilang (tested for EN/DE/FR/IT) solution. (full days are always saved with a 00:00 timetag)

```
let dateParts = moment(DATE).calendar().split(' '),
    index = dateParts.indexOf('00:00');

// ['Yesterday', 'at', '00:00', 'PM'] -> ['Yesterday']
dateParts.length = (index !== -1 ? (index - 1) : dateParts.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `moment.js` locales won't change, I wrote a simple wrapper function around `moment().calendar()` for the following languages that I use:

**en, ar, bg, cs, da, de, el, es, et, fi, fr-ca, fr, he, hr, hu, hy-am, it, ja, kk, ko, lt, nl, nb, pl, pt, ro, ru, sk, sl, sr, sv, th, tr, uk, vi, zh-cn, zh-tw**

You can add new or remove existing cases inside the switch statement based on your needs and it should still work just fine.

```js
const timeRegExp = /[0-9:,]/g;
const dateRegExp = /[0-9.-/]/g;

const removeLastNWords = (str, n, separator) => {
  return `${str.split(' ').splice(0, n).join(separator)}`;
}

const removeDigitsAndTimeChars = (str) => {
  return `${str.replace(timeRegExp, '').trimEnd()}`;
}

const removeLastNWordsStripped = (str, n, separator) => {
  return removeDigitsAndTimeChars(removeLastNWords(str, n, separator));
}

const calendarNoTime = (inp, strict) => {
  const originalCalendarDate = moment(inp, strict).calendar();
  const parts = originalCalendarDate.split(' ');
    
  /**
   * Most languages use the 'L' format for calendar: { sameElse },
   * these have parts of length 1. zh-cn does not use a space to separate 
   * the time from the date, so remove it if present otherwise keep 
   * the 'L' format. If `cn` not needed, simply return parts[0]. 
   * `sr/sl` uses spaces to separate day, month, year.  
   * 
   */
  if (parts.length === 1 || dateRegExp.test(parts[0])) {
    return parts[0].includes(':') ? removeDigitsAndTimeChars(parts[0]) : parts.join(' ');
  }

  switch (moment.locale()) {

    /**
     * These languages have a preposition with a length of < 3 
     * before the time. Find that preposition and keep the words
     * till that preposition. If `ru` not needed,
     * use removeLastNWords(originalCalendarDate, prepositionIndex, ' ')
     * 
     */
    case 'bg':
    case 'cs':
    case 'de':
    case 'es':
    case 'en':
    case 'fr':
    case 'fr-ca':
    case 'hr':
    case 'nl':
    case 'pl':
    case 'pt':
    case 'ro':
    case 'ru':
    case 'sk':
    case 'sl':
    case 'sr':
    case 'uk':
      const prepositionIndex = parts.findIndex((part, i) => i !== 0 && part.length < 3);
      return removeLastNWordsStripped(originalCalendarDate, prepositionIndex, ' ');

      /**
       * Less strict than the above, these languages put their preposition at
       * next to last index inside the `parts` array to every wording.
       * 
       */
    case 'da':
    case 'fi':
    case 'it':
    case 'kk':
    case 'nb':
    case 'th':
    case 'vi':
      return removeLastNWords(originalCalendarDate, parts.length - 2, ' ');

      // Uses [dddd, XX:XX] format, remove digits and special characters
    case 'et':
    case 'ja':
    case 'ko':
    case 'lt':
    case 'sv':
    case 'zh-tw':
    case 'zh-cn':
      return removeDigitsAndTimeChars(originalCalendarDate);

      // Same as above expect the preposition is at parts.length - 3
    case 'el':
      return removeLastNWords(originalCalendarDate, parts.length - 3, ' ');

      // Same as above + [dddd LT] format for some days
    case 'hy-am':
      return parts.length < 3 ? parts[0] : removeLastNWords(originalCalendarDate, parts.length - 3, ' ');

      // Same as above, preposition is at parts.length - 2
    case 'tr':
      return parts.length < 3 ? parts[0] : removeLastNWords(originalCalendarDate, parts.length - 2, ' ');

      // Appends `kor` to time, remove the word that contains this substring
    case 'hu':
      return originalCalendarDate.replace(/ *\b\S*?kor\S*\b/g, '');

      // Custom formats 
      // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/
    case 'ar':
      return moment(inp).calendar({
        sameDay: '[اليوم]',
        nextDay: '[غدًا]',
        nextWeek: 'dddd',
        lastDay: '[أمس]',
        lastWeek: 'dddd',
        sameElse: 'L',
      });
    case 'he':
      return moment(inp).calendar({
        sameDay: '[היום]',
        nextDay: '[מחר]',
        nextWeek: 'dddd',
        lastDay: '[אתמול]',
        lastWeek: 'dddd',
        sameElse: 'L',
      });

      // Unsupported language, use default format with time
    default:
      return originalCalendarDate;
  }
}


const today = new Date();
const yesterday = (new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 1);
const coupleDaysAgo = (new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 2);
const fewDaysAgo = (new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 4);
const manyDaysAgo = (new Date()).setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 7);
const supportedLanguages = ['en', 'ar', 'bg', 'cs', 'da', 'de', 'el', 'es', 'et', 'fi', 'fr-ca', 'fr', 'he', 'hr', 'hu', 'hy-am', 'it', 'ja', 'kk', 'ko', 'lt', 'nl', 'nb', 'pl', 'pt', 'ro', 'ru', 'sk', 'sl', 'sr', 'sv', 'th', 'tr', 'uk', 'vi', 'zh-cn', 'zh-tw'];
let allDays = [];

supportedLanguages.forEach((lang) => {
  moment.locale(lang);
  allDays = [calendarNoTime(today), calendarNoTime(yesterday), calendarNoTime(coupleDaysAgo), calendarNoTime(fewDaysAgo), calendarNoTime(manyDaysAgo)];

  document.write(`${lang}: `);
  document.write(allDays.join(', '));
  document.write('</br>');
});
```

And for the TypeScript fans:

```
const removeLastNWords = (str: string, n: number, separator: string): string => {}
const removeDigitsAndDateChars = (str: string): string => {}
const removeLastNWordsStripped = (str: string, n: number, separator: string): string => {}
const calendarNoTime = (inp?: moment.MomentInput, strict?: boolean): string => {}
```

And also a [**fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/jngqs25v/20/)

**Edit 1**
Fixed **he, sr, sl** languages. Updated fiddle to display all the supported language dates.