# Updating Moment.js Calendar

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Like many before me (notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420447/moment-calendar-without-the-time)), I'm trying to display relative times without a date using moment.calendar.  However, I can't seem to get the answer to work for me.

```
var today = moment(new Date()).startOf('Day');
today.calendar();
// Displays Today at 12:00 AM

  moment.updateLocale(null, {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday]',
        sameDay : '[Today] With just the date?',
        nextDay : '[Tomorrow]',
        lastWeek : 'll',
        nextWeek : 'll',
        sameElse : 'll'
    }
    });

today.calendar();
// Displays Today at 12:00 AM
```

I would expect it to display "Today With just the date?".

Here is my attempt at a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WonkoTheSane/aoqr7x5v/11/) (based on another excellent moment basics [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesWClark/9PAFg/) example - credit where credit is due)

Comment: Note that the "With just the date?" string was just meant to see something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`updateLocale`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/) passing `'en'` as first parameter (since *By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale strings*). Moreover you have to create a new moment object to see updated calendar strings:

```js
var today = moment(new Date()).startOf('Day');
console.log(today.calendar()); // Displays Today at 12:00 AM

moment.updateLocale('en', {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday]',
        sameDay : '[Today] [With just the date?]',
        nextDay : '[Tomorrow]',
        lastWeek : 'll',
        nextWeek : 'll',
        sameElse : 'll'
    }
});

moment.updateLocale('fr', {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Hier]',
        sameDay : '[Aujourd’hui] L',
        nextDay : '[Demain]',
        lastWeek : 'll',
        nextWeek : 'll',
        sameElse : 'll'
    }
});
var today2 = moment().startOf('day');
console.log(today2.locale('en').calendar());
console.log(today2.locale('fr').calendar());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Use `sameDay : '[Today] L'` if you want current date, instead of the string `"With just the date?"`.

Comment: This gets me close - I didn't realize I needed a new object.  However, changing the locale to, say, 'fr' doesn't appear to localize any of the output (at least in Fiddle, and if I copy your answer snippet here)

Comment: I can't understand which is exactly your issue with other locales, anyway I've updated my snippet to provide a code sample using `'fr'` locale.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify the locale name to be updated, and after update, create the moment object.

Additionally, `With just the date?` is not a valid format specifier for MomentJS. If you need to show it, you need to enclose it in `[]`. Still, you can use it to see some jumbled string on the console:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  calendar: {
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    sameDay: '[Today] With just the date?',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    lastWeek: 'll',
    nextWeek: 'll',
    sameElse: 'll'
  }
});

var today = moment(new Date()).startOf('Day');
console.log(today.calendar());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```