How can I delete time from date in moment().calendar()?
I am trying to get Today and Tomorrow titles from date using Moment Calendar.
In case moment(date).calendar() I get Tomorrow at 12:00 AM. But I need without time. Just Tomorrow
In case moment(date).calendar(null, { nextDay: [Tomorrow] }) I get Tomorrow. But localization not working.
In case moment(date).calendar('uk', { nextDay: '[Tomorrow]' }) I get 05/22/2024
I cannot use smth like split(' ')[0] because there are languages like Arabic.
So I need Today Tomorrow with localization

Might be this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65319457/3670942

Thanks. I did with translations. Without moment calendar
